# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-datetime

Why does this error keep showing up? I am just trying to create a table.
The code for this is below:

```
import datetime


q= datetime.date(2004,12,25)

e= datetime.date(2019,11,23) 

f= datetime.date(2019,11,26)

p= datetime.date(2004,12,13)

nam=[["attack on titan",10,"completed",p,q],["one punch man",10,"WATCHING",e,f]]

print("|         NAME           | SCORE |   STATUS   |  DATE STARTED  |    DATE ENDED   |") 

for KI in nam:
  print("|",KI[0]," "*22-len(KI[0]),"|"," ",KI[1]," ","|",KI[2]," "*(10-len(KI[2])),"|",""*2,KI[3], 
         " "*2,"|"," "*3,KI[4]," "*2,"|")
```

Don't give too much attention to the space multiplication.

Error:

```
|         NAME           | SCORE |   STATUS   |  DATE STARTED  |    DATE ENDED   |


Traceback (most recent call last):


    line 9, in <module>

    print("|",KI[0]," "*22-len(KI[0]),"|"," ",KI[1]," ","|",KI[2]," "*(10-len(KI[2])),"|"," "*2,KI[3]," "*2,"|"," "*3,KI[4]," "*2,"|")


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
.........................................................................................
```

Comment: Are you trying to create spaces in the table by `" "*22-len(KI[0]` as KI[0] is "attack on titan"?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do.This will fill in the spaces that were left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring with `" "*22-len(KI[0])`.
`" "*22` is a string consisting of 22 spaces and `len(KI[0])` is an integer.
As the `TypeError` is telling you, subtracting an integer from a string doesn't make sense.
I'm guessing you're intention is `" "*(22-len(KI[0]))`.